# Datatables.net excel export size is huge and can't download in IE 11/Edge but can in Chrome

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, datatables, microsoft-edge, jszip

I've a data set of ~60,000 records with 20 columns. I'm using buttons export using Html5Excel. Also, i'm using JSZip as well.

When i export the excel, the excel size is approximately 54 MB. However, when i open this excel and save as the file size is around 7 MB which is around 12 times lesser than the original downloaded file.

Is there any way we can reduce the downloaded file size? It's taking around 1 minute to download in Chrome. However, this is completely failing in IE 11 and Edge browsers.

Are there any alternates to download this much big file in IE 11 and Edge, as currently for our customers we can't suggest to use Chrome browser.

Comment: This is being tracked here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39534/

Comment: Also, this is tracked here at https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/387